# Hyperlink not working on pdf

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, hyperlink

I have a word document with a hyperlink that I want to save as pdf. However, when the document is as pdf, the hyperlink does not work anymore. I want to mention that I did save as and not print as pdf. Would you know a solution to this problem? Is there perhaps a tool I could download or should I save as another format? but I really need to get the pdf version and not the word document version. Many thanks

Comment: Does the link appear in the PDF as the URL, or do you have some other word or phrase that displays, with the link associated with it? Also - which version of Windows, which version of Word? Are you using Microsoft's built-in "print to PDF", or an add-on PDF "printer"?

Comment: While  ou have self answered the question, the question still should include enough details to help others to find it / know that it might be helpful for them.

Answer (score 1):

finally found the issue, I have a mac and was using word document from windows which does not allow the hyperlink to work when I saved as pdf. However, if I use Pages from mac and then I convert as pdf the hyperlink is working! Many thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

I did what you said and it works perfectly. I have Word from Office 365 suite. Try opening the `pdf` in a web browser and see if the problem persists.

If you really need a convertor, try [this](https://www.ilovepdf.com/word_to_pdf)